# Applying weird gating quickly to pandas data

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, pandas-groupby

So for another in a long series of weird data processing questions, I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                 id        tof
0              10.0  2004847.0
1              10.0  2066116.0
2              10.0  5441996.0
3              10.0  5642443.0
4              15.0  1979815.0
5              15.0  1992399.0
6              15.0  2008208.0
7              15.0  2098060.0
8              15.0  3980280.0
9              27.0  2027878.0
10             27.0  2047992.0
11             27.0  5308106.0
12             27.0  6743403.0
```

and I wanted to apply a gate on the data, grouped by ID. I wanted to only keep data such that the tof sums to a range of numbers, and the difference is between a range of numbers.

For example, I would have `tof_sum = [7000000,80000000]`, `tof_dif = [3000000,3500000]`, the gate would keep rows 0 2, since their sum is between the numbers above, as is their difference. It would also keep row 1, because of its relationship with row 2. However, it wouldn't keep any rows with id 15, since no two rows sum to over 7000000.

I could imagine setting up

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[k, c0, c1] for k, tof in Da.groupby('id').tof
                              for c0, c1 in combinations(tof, 2)
                                ], columns=['id', 'tof0', 'tof1'])
```

which generates all combinations pairwise for each id and then compairing them across like this:

```
      id       tof0       tof1
0   10.0  2004847.0  2066116.0 (sum not bigger than 7000000, next)
1   10.0  2004847.0  5441996.0 (this sum is in range, difference is in range, ✓)
2   10.0  2004847.0  5642443.0 (sum and difference are in range here too, ✓ )
3   10.0  2066116.0  5441996.0 (etc, etc)
4   10.0  2066116.0  5642443.0
5   10.0  5441996.0  5642443.0
6   15.0  1979815.0  1992399.0
7   15.0  1979815.0  2008208.0
8   15.0  1979815.0  2098060.0
9   15.0  1979815.0  3980280.0
10  15.0  1992399.0  2008208.0
11  15.0  1992399.0  2098060.0
12  15.0  1992399.0  3980280.0
13  15.0  2008208.0  2098060.0
14  15.0  2008208.0  3980280.0
15  15.0  2098060.0  3980280.0
16  27.0  2027878.0  2047992.0
17  27.0  2027878.0  5308106.0
18  27.0  2027878.0  6743403.0
19  27.0  2047992.0  5308106.0
20  27.0  2047992.0  6743403.0
21  27.0  5308106.0  6743403.0
```

and every time it satisfies the condition of sum and difference being within their respective ranges, it would save the rows with those tof's.

BUT this command takes an amazingly long time (like minutes) for the multi-million line data datafile I have to work with.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add an expected output, so we can visually see what you try to do

Comment: @Erfan edited for clarity

Comment: 1. A few minutes is not a long time to handle multi-million line data. 2. Do you want to keep the rows, or do you want to keep the *pairs*?

Comment: @QuangHoang I would want to keep the rows, but I guess keeping the pairs as well as the informations about the pairs would be helpful since I could do further gating later without doing the same realy long generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, a few minutes is not a long time to handle multi-million line data. You can vectorize the process by broadcasting:

```
def get_pairs(g):
    x = g.tof.values

    # upper triangle matrix to avoid duplicate pairs: (a,b) and (b,a)
    uniques = np.arange(len(x)) > np.arange(len(x))[:, None]

    sums = x + x[:, None]
    sum_mask = (sums>7000000) & (sums<80000000)

    diffs = np.abs(x - x[:, None])
    diff_mask = (diffs > 3000000) & (diffs < 3500000)

    mask = sum_mask & diff_mask & uniques

    ret_df = pd.DataFrame(mask, index=x, columns=x)
    ret_df = ret_df.stack()
    return ret_df[ret_df]
```

Then

```
new_df = df.groupby('id').apply(get_pairs).reset_index().drop(0, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     id    level_1    level_2
0  10.0  2004847.0  5441996.0
1  10.0  2066116.0  5441996.0
2  27.0  2027878.0  5308106.0
3  27.0  2047992.0  5308106.0
```

---

A slight modification gives you the indices of the rows, which, you can use to filter the original data:

```
def get_pairs(g):
    x = g.tof.values

    # upper triangle matrix
    uniques = np.arange(len(x)) > np.arange(len(x))[:, None]

    sums = x + x[:, None]
    sum_mask = (sums>7000000) & (sums<80000000)

    diffs = np.abs(x - x[:, None])
    diff_mask = (diffs > 3000000) & (diffs < 3500000)

    mask = sum_mask & diff_mask & uniques

    # note the different columns and index.
    ret_df = pd.DataFrame(mask, index=g.index, columns=g.index)
    ret_df = ret_df.stack()
    return ret_df[ret_df]
```

Output:

```
     id  level_1  level_2
0  10.0        0        2
1  10.0        1        2
2  27.0        9       11
3  27.0       10       11
```

Comment: @GZ0 good point. It only creates three matrices per group of id. So it really depends on the data.

Comment: Im quite confused about the output, mine outputs something like ```0  2    True
1  2    True
2  4    True
   5    True
   6    True
   7    True
dtype: bool ``` . is this some multi-index thing that I could then use to mask the original dataframe?

Comment: Notice the `reset_index().drop(0, axis=1)` in the assignment of `new_df`.

Comment: Actually, the original constraints could be rewritten into two contraints on the larger number of a pair and the diff of the pair. Selecting pairs using the new contraints could reduce quite some computation.

Comment: @GZ0 True, but my math is not working properly now. We can certainly compute the sum/diff matrix like: `x_large + x_small[:,None]` and reduce computation by roughly 4 times already.